# Syncing telerik and google calendar

Tags: c#, telerik

I'm currently developing some new features on a C#/Silverlight web application, those new features include managing appointments and calendar of several hundred users. 
I'll be using Telerik controls to do so.

The users will soon migrate to gmail so I'd like to be able to schedule an appointment in someone's calendar and send this appointment to their brand new Google Calendar...

I read quite a few others posts concerning direct syncing between telerik and gcalendar and came to understand that it's not possible at the moment.

I know it is possible to export appointments to iCal format, however I have no clue on how to automate the process (only push to google), with all the constraints that this implies (authentication for instance).

Has anyone ever done something close to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this if you use OAuth to authenticate against the calendar.  The Telerik controls can display the content you fetch from a Google Calendar once you format them appropriately for the schedule control that you are working with.